# Cannot reconnect to Apache Derby (Embedded) server Ubuntu 20.04 Eclipse

Tags: derby

New to this site so bear with me.. I'm developing web project on JVM, generated by Maven and coded in Eclipse I2E. Whenever I want to change server side code (add/delete/modify), I stop the Apache Tomcat server in the Eclipse 'servers' tab, applly changes and then restart the server. This procedure works fine on Windows 10, **however**, on Ubuntu 20.04 I get : 'Failed to start database [dbname] with classloader..' exception in this line:

this.connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB.dbURL); //DB.dbURL = jdbc:derby:C:/final_project/ClientsDB;create=true

If I delete the databse and start over, it works fine.

I'm using Eclipse I2E on Ubuntu 20.04, Tomcat 9, Derby 10 and fire up eclispe using sudo -H eclipse